# Перехват введенного, но не отправленного текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, input

Есть консольный чат для общения внутри сети.
Сам чатик работает, но если в момент ввода сообщения (еще до отправки, до нажатия энтера) юзером 1 приходит сообщение от юзера 2 - то случается неприятность: ведь сообщение выводится в строку где набирается текст, и в итоге получается так, как на картинке. Самое грустное, что сбрасывается весь набранный текст, который потом надо снова набирать.
Я искал способы решения проблемы, почитал про sys stdin,  но мне не помогло.

Есть какие-то способы перехватить набранный текст до того, как он отправлен, при наступлении определенного события (в данном случае при получении сообщения)?

[image: До]

[image: После]

```
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
import select
import threading
import time


def intro():
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    a = s.getsockname()[0]
    print('Your local IP: ' + a)
    s.close()
    b = input('Enter your port: ')
    c = input('Enter target ip: ')
    d = input('Enter target port: ')
    return a, b, c, d


def recieve_message(timed):
    for i in range(timed):
        try:
            (data, addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
            print('\r>> [IN]: ' + data.decode("utf-8") + ' ' + '\n< [OUT]: ', end='')
        except:
            pass



def send_message(outputs):
    for ii in range(outputs):
        try:
            myMessage = input('< [OUT]: ')
            mySocket.sendto(myMessage.encode('utf-8'), (SERVER_IP, HIS_PORT_NUMBER))
        except:
            pass


timed = 43200
outputs = 10000
SIZE = 1024

a, b, c, d = intro()
hostName = gethostbyname(a)
MY_PORT_NUMBER = int(b)
HIS_PORT_NUMBER = int(d)
SERVER_IP = c
mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
mySocket.bind((hostName, MY_PORT_NUMBER))
mySocket.settimeout(1)

print('Connecting...')
print('')

recieve = threading.Thread(target=recieve_message, args=(timed,))
send = threading.Thread(target=send_message, args=(outputs,))
recieve.start()
send.start()
```

Comment: может стоит переписать все на ncurses?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Вы используете [разделяемый ресурс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81) и никак страхуетесь от одновременного доступа к этому ресурсу других клиентов. Стандартное решение -- [мьютекс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81). В пакете threading они также есть. Таким образом, перед тем, как осуществлять вывод, Вам требуется захватить мьютекс так, чтобы никто другой не смог осуществлять вывод. К сожалению, Вашу ошибку я воспроизвести не смог нормально. Поэтому предлагаю общую схему использования мьютекса:

глобальная область видимости:

```
import threading
mutex = threading.Lock()
```

поток 1:

```
mutex.acquire()
print('My-message')
mutex.release()
```

поток 2:

```
mutex.acquire()
print('My-message')
mutex.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать установить `readchar` и читать по одному символу, но проверял на windows

```
import readchar
import threading
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

x = ""

def resieve_imitation():
    while True:
        sleep(4)
        stdout.write('\nIN:EXTERN_MESSAGE\n[OUT]:' + x)

recieve = threading.Thread(target=resieve_imitation)
recieve.start()

stdout.write('\n[OUT]:')

while True:
    k = readchar.readkey()
    stdout.write(k)
    stdout.flush()
    x += k
```

Естественно надо добавить проверку завершения ввода по Enter и "закрыть" обработку одного символа мьютексом, чтобы другой поток не "вклинился" между операторами.